# how to get the address with /proc/kallsyms

Tags: programming, debugging

> cat /proc/kallsyms | grep "\ doexecve$"

i run this command in ubuntu 13.04 in virtual box in order to get address. However, no result. How to get the address for kprobe debug

Answer (score 3):

You should execute the following command to enable `kallsyms` first:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0  > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict"
```